# RESTful API: "download resource" end point name

Tags: rest

I'm building a RESTful api that should support a GET request to download one of the server resources (a file)

I wonder what is the correct name (route) I should give this request (assuming there is one).

I've read some of the "best practices" articles I found but none of them didn't relate to this scenario.

I alreay have:

```
[GET] /files/file-id
```

that returns information about the file so I need something else.
Is there a best practice to RESTful download requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Accept` header should control what your endpoint returns. For example, if the header requests XML or JSON, that would return the file information, but if the header requests something like base64 or the generic binary type `application/octet-stream`, typically that would return the file itself.

That's what "representational" means in REST. Nothing really returns the resource itself (in theory) -- you return a *representation* of the resource based on what the client has requested.

Comment: Highly recommend to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49368738/1335142). While the `Accept` header might be the best approach but an additional endpoint like `GET /documents/:id/content` is more practical and doesn't require additional logic on a frontend and you can just use an URL to get content of the file.

Answer (score 2):

`[GET] /files/file-id` should suffice. It is in line with common practices such that an experienced developer could look at that route and they would be able to correctly assume what that route does.