# Which is the best approach for picking a resource to download a file with a RestApi?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I need to download a file, but, I am wondering which is the best approach to publish my resource.
Lets say I have a Document

```
http://api/documents/id
```

where I make a GET request should I receive the information of the document with that id including an extra field with the string representation of the file in BASE64? or should I publish another url resource like

```
http://api/documents/id/download
```

just for getting the file? The first I know how to do it, but I don't know if that is the proper way. With the later I need advice.

Answer (score 4):

On my understanding your `document` resource consists of both metadata and the actual content of the document. So you could support the following:

- `GET /documents/:id`: Return a representation of the metadata of the document
- `GET /documents/:id/content`: Return a representation of the content of the document

---

Alternatively you could support a single endpoint such as `GET /documents/:id` and return both metadata and content in a multipart response.

---

Content negotiation would be the best approach though. You could use a single endpoint such as `GET /documents/:id` and `Accept: application/json` for the metadata and, for example, `Accept: application/octet-stream` for the content.

Comment: What about passing on the header an Accept where based of what you post you receive the file or not? for example, if you send a get with Accept : application/json, it means that the client will get the resource via json. Can you add a specific type for that on the accept? like Accept: application/file?

Comment: I think Accept header is used for different representations of the same response i.e. JSON vs XML. Seems like a pretty unusual way to differentiate content vs metadata.

Answer (score -1):

how about

`GET /documents/:id` for metadata
`GET /documents/:id?action=download` for content